# Correcting the GCC command line ordering using Automake

Tags: linux, gcc, autotools, automake

I have an autotools project that compiles just fine on the Mac, but under Linux (Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS) the command lines passed to `gcc` have the libraries out of order relative to the object files. For example, autotools generates the following command to compile my code, a single file named `test.c` into a binary named `test`:

```
gcc -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -g -O2 -lglib-2.0 -o test test-test.o
```

This command line fails with:

```
/home/user/glib-test/test.c:4: undefined reference to `g_malloc`
/home/user/glib-test/test.c:5: undefined reference to `g_free`
```

However, if I compile from the command line and switch it up so the library reference is after the object files it works just fine:

```
gcc -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -g -O2 -o test test-test.o -lglib-2.0
```

The challenge is that I can't figure out how to force Autotools to generate the command line in the right order. For the sake of clarity, I've reproduced the simple test case here. First up is `configure.ac`:

```
dnl Process this file with autoconf to produce a configure script.

AC_PREREQ(2.59)
AC_INIT(glib-test, 1.0)

AC_CANONICAL_SYSTEM
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE()

AC_PROG_CC
AM_PROG_CC_C_O
PKG_CHECK_MODULES(GLIB, glib-2.0 > 2.0)
AC_CONFIG_FILES(Makefile)
AC_OUTPUT
```

Next is the simple `Makefile.am`:

```
CFLAGS=-Wall
bin_PROGRAMS=test
test_CFLAGS=$(GLIB_CFLAGS)
test_LDFLAGS=$(GLIB_LIBS)
test_SOURCES=test.c
```

Finally, the source code to this minimal test case, `test.c`:

```
#include <glib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    gchar *foo = g_malloc(100);
    g_free(foo);
    return 0;
}
```

Compilation is then achieved using the following series of commands:

```
touch NEWS README AUTHORS ChangeLog
aclocal
autoconf
automake --add-missing
./configure
make
```

I should be clear, I understand why my code won't compile, I'm just wondering how to get `automake` to put the libraries at the end of the command line so `gcc` will execute and link properly. It should be noted that `gcc` on Mac OS X Lion doesn't seem to have this problem.

Comment: "gcc on Mac OS X Lion doesn't seem to have this problem." - it doesn't, because Apple uses a fork of GCC 4.2, whereas this behavior was introduced in a newer version of GCC (IIRC in GCC 4.5).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The solution turned out to be the difference between `LDFLAGS` and `LDADD`. In short `LDFLAGS` is added before the object files on the command line and `LDADD` is added afterwards. Thus, changing `Makefile.am` to the following solved the problem:

```
CFLAGS=-Wall
bin_PROGRAMS=test
test_CFLAGS=$(GLIB_CFLAGS)
test_LDADD=$(GLIB_LIBS)
test_SOURCES=test.c
```

It only took tracking down a GCC developer at work to solve. Also, this example I provided is rather poor because `test` has a defined meaning in some contexts of autotools.

Comment: Note that the automake documentation clearly states that LDADD is the wrong place for `-l` flags.  Although this works, it doesn't smell right.

Comment: @William: The Automake doc says "`PROG_LDADD` is inappropriate for passing program-specific linker flags (**except** for `-l`, `-L`, `-dlopen` and `-dlpreopen`)."

Comment: @adl  The exception in the documentation does not appear in the documentation for 1.11.1 (section 8.1.2).  Do you know why this exception came to be acceptable?  Or was it always okay, just undocumented?

Comment: @WilliamPursell: it's in the documentation for Automake 1.12.5 (current version) that is available online at http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Linking.html

Comment: @WilliamPursell: I'm pretty sure the exception is old.  I can find it in the documentation of Automake 1.4.

Answer (score 1):

I solved a similar problem. The ./configure script in question was unable to complete a check for presence of a function due to a missing symbol. If I added the correct library to `$LDFLAGS` or such like, it was added before the `.c` file and the library was ignored.

The names of functions to check are first added to `ac_func_list` and then there is a loop in the body of the `./configure` that for each of them calls `ac_fn_c_check_func ()` and that in turns calls `ac_fn_c_try_link ()`

the checking function ac_fn_c_try_link () uses a command of this pattern:

```
ac_link='$CC -o conftest$ac_exeext $CFLAGS $CPPFLAGS \
         $LDFLAGS conftest.$ac_ext $LIBS >&5'
```

`$LDADD` is completely ignored here. Therefore the only solution here is to add the `-l` flags to variable `$LIBS`.