# Autotools build fails while linking

Tags: gcc, linker, g++, gnu, autotools

I have a project that I am working on converting over to autotools.

Here are the relevant files

**configure.ac**

```
AC_INIT([opengl-es-demo], [1])
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([-Wall -Werror foreign])
AC_LANG(C++)
AC_PROG_CXX
PKG_CHECK_MODULES(LIBPNG, libpng >= 1.6.34)
PKG_CHECK_MODULES(FREETYPE2, freetype2 >= 21.0.15)
PKG_CHECK_MODULES(EGL, egl > 0)
PKG_CHECK_MODULES(GLES2, glesv2 > 0)
PKG_CHECK_MODULES(PTHREAD, pthread-stubs > 0)
AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile])
AC_OUTPUT
```

**Makefile.am**

```
bin_PROGRAMS = main
main_SOURCES = main.cpp eglManager.cpp shaderManager.cpp imageUtils.cpp freetypeUtils.cpp texture.cpp shader.cpp camera.cpp
main_CPPFLAGS = $(FREETYPE2_CFLAGS) $(LIBPNG_CFLAGS) $(EGL_CFLAGS) $(GLES2_CFLAGS) $(PTHREAD_CFLAGS)
main_LDFLAGS = $(FREETYPE2_LIBS) $(LIBPNG_LIBS) $(EGL_LIBS) $(GLES2_LIBS) $(PTHREAD_LIBS)
```

The linker calls this step...

```
g++  -g -O2 -lfreetype -lpng16 -lz -lEGL -lGLESv2   -o main main-main.o main-eglManager.o main-shaderManager.o main-imageUtils.o main-freetypeUtils.o main-texture.o main-shader.o main-camera.o
```

...and then fails with a bunch of undefined reference errors to functions found in OpenGL(-GLESv2), png(-lpng16), and freetype(-lfreetype) libraries.

It compiled fine when I wasn't using autotools (only a makefile) so I know the problem is with my autotools usage.

Where did I mess up the configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing `main_LDFLAGS` to `main_LDADD` solved the problem.

[Correcting the GCC command line ordering using Automake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13610572/correcting-the-gcc-command-line-ordering-using-automake)